# Having two controlling field in a object

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist

I have a few field object which is country, weight and postage rate. Each of them is a picklist data type. What I want is, when the user chooses country and weight, it will affect the postage rate. Usually, we can use a controlling field. However, I don't think we can use it for 2 fields.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using the standard tools; There is [an Idea (11 years old)](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br1aAAC) that you should vote up

Workarounds would be Visualforce or a custom LWC

Comment: Is it means that we cannot implement this with the current salesforce?

Comment: It means you need to code a custom LWC or VF page that accepts the country and weight and presents the postage weight based on doing a lookup from custom objects or custom metadata where your table of postage rates exists in normalized form

Comment: I see, thank you.